# using select statement to define a default column value in create table syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql, ddl

I am trying to create a table and for one of the columns i want the default value to be specific- please see the code beneath:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PSTest(
modDate datetime default getdate()
, [Date] datetime default (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()))
);
```

I am getting the following error

```
Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

I understand that i cant do this, but is there a way around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Will `Date` always be for the same day as `modDate`? If so, a computed column would almost certainly be a better option.

Comment: nope. the modDate will be datetime but in the Date i dont want any element of time output. just purely the yyyy-mm-dd without the time extension. with the current answer i get the output on modDate as-         2015-09-22 14:02:31.870 and on the date as         2015-09-22 00:00:00.000. i dont want the time at all in date column

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I asked. I was asking if the two columns are *always* going to have two related values (I.e. if `modDate` is ever updated, will `Date` also be updated to the matching day)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PSTest(
    modDate datetime default getdate(),
    [Date] datetime default cast(getdate() as date)
);
```

Comment: ok so that is fine but when i insert data into the table, the date column gives the output as 2015-09-22 00:00:00.000. i dont want that time to show at all there.

Comment: @FaizSaiyed - then declare it as `date`, not `datetime`. You've given it a datatype that has a time component. It has to be set to *something*.

Comment: yup that also works. just got told that if i have the 0's at the end its fine. but thank you all#

Comment: @FaizSaiyed FYI a date can usually be formatted in whatever client application/reporting tool you are using. It is rare that business folks are looking directly at the output from a SQL query window.